# trouble with composite rotation and translation in opengl, moving object about its own local axis is not working

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, transformation, vbo, coordinate-transformation

I am building a robot in openGL and it should move and rotate. When I press the robot should move forward and if I press t then he should rotate 15* about its own local axis and then if i press f he will walk again. I have done, the robot walks and rotates but the problem is he is not rotating with respect to his local axis, he is following (0,0,0). I think i dont understand how the composition of translation and rotation has to be made so that I get my desired effect.

I am trying now with just a scaled sphere. I am adding the display func here, so that it is more clear for you guys:

```
void display() 
{ 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    // need depth test to correctly draw 3D objects 
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    //All color and material stuffs go here
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); 
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); 
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);   // normalize normals 

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); 
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE); 

    // set up the parameters for lighting 
    GLfloat light_ambient[] = {0,0,0,1}; 
    GLfloat light_diffuse[] = {.6,.6,.6,1};
    GLfloat light_specular[] = {1,1,1,1}; 
    GLfloat light_pos[] = {10,10,10,1}; 

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient); 
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse); 
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular); 


    GLfloat mat_specular[] = {.9, .9, .9,1}; 
    GLfloat mat_shine[] = {10}; 
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular); 
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mat_shine); 
    //color specs ends ////////////////////////////////////////

    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE); // comment this line to enable polygon shades

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 
    gluPerspective(90, 1, 1, 100); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glLoadIdentity(); 

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_pos); 

    gluLookAt(0,0,30,0,0,0,0,1,0); 

    glRotatef(x_angle, 0, 1,0); // this is just for mouse handling
    glRotatef(y_angle, 1,0,0); // this is just for mouse handling
    glScalef(scale_size, scale_size, scale_size); // for zooming effect

    draw_coordinate();

    //Drawing using VBO starts here
    glTranslatef(walk*sin(M_PI*turn/180),0,walk*cos(M_PI*turn/180));
    glRotatef(turn,0,1,0);
    draw_sphere(3,1,1);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // enable the vertex array on the client side
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); // enable the normal array on the client side    


    glutSwapBuffers(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rotatefunction from opengl is one that rotates around (0,0,0). You have to translate the rotationpoint to the center and then do the rotation.

```
...
glTranslatef(walk*sin(M_PI*turn/180),0,walk*cos(M_PI*turn/180));
glTranslatef(-x_rot,-y_rot,-z_rot);
glRotatef(turn,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(x_rot,y_rot,z_rot);
...
```

So In your case `x_rot=walk*sin(M_PI*turn/180)`, `y_rot=0` and `z_rot=walk*cos(M_PI*turn/180)`. The above becomes:

```
...
glRotatef(turn,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(x_rot=walk*sin(M_PI*turn/180),0,walk*cos(M_PI*turn/180));
...
```

Comment: Thanks hamon for the reply, yes I know that, I tried that in my earlier code, I think i didnot do it properly, I am going to try again this approach, here turn is angle i want to rotate the object , can you tell me what are x_rot, y_rot and z_rot? how to find the values for these three? My scene is going to be a walking robot, so i belive I have to keep track and for each iteration i need to find values for these three variabls?

Comment: These x_rot, y_rot and z_rot are the coords of the point where you want to rotate around, e.g. the center of you robot. So yes you need to keep track of those variables in some way.

Comment: well I tried that,

glTranslatef(walk*sin(M_PI*turn/180),0,walk*cos(M_PI*turn/180));
glTranslatef(0,0,walk);
glRotatef(turn,0,1,0);
glTranslatef(0,0,-walk);
draw_sphere(3,1,1);


here walk initially is 0 and I have a sphere at (0,0,0) now if press f once, the sphere is translated to (0,0,walk), so center comes to (0,0,walk) also, so i tried that but did not work.. am I going wrong here?

Comment: And what are the results? Your robot has to rotate in some way?

Comment: if I do the following

glTranslatef(walk*sin(M_PI*turn/180),0,walk*cos(M_PI*turn/180));
 glTranslatef(0,0,walk);
 glRotatef(turn,0,1,0);
 glTranslatef(0,0,-walk);
 draw_sphere(3,1,1);


he always moves forward, not in the direction he is facing after rotation. rotation is working seems.

Answer (score 0):

If your robot doesn't rotate in its own axis then translate the robot to the center, rotate it and again translate it back to the original position. Keep your translation, rotation, scaling and drawing inside

```
glPushMatrix();
........your rotation,translation,scalling,drawing goes here..........
glPopMatrix();
```

These keeps the scene same.
If you don't understand these function then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031842/how-do-glpushmatrix-and-glpopmatrix-keep-the-scene-the-same).