# where should glPushMatrix() be declared?

Tags: opengl

I am trying to make a second hand that rotates each second like in a clock.I am not clearly understanding what glpushmatrix() and glpopmatrix() does in opengl .When should i use it and where should i declare it .Is it before drawing an object of after drawing an object.Also,does glpushmatrix() push the matrix of all the objects in the viewport as a whole or does it push just the matrix of a specified object.

Comment: Similar question with an excellent reply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7031981/1198654

Comment: The answer that glampert points to will answer the question, but if you're just learning OpenGL, you shouldn't waste time doing it the old way. `glPushMatrix()` and related functions are deprecated and only available when using legacy OpenGL. You should move to modern OpenGL and pass all matrices into your shaders instead.